# What is the less confusing way to explain confidence intervals to a beginner

Tags: statistics, education

Let us say that you are back in high school and you have a friend who has missed class for a week. He needs information  to be spoonfed to him, because its not his style to overthink. If you push for the overly conceptual he'll get frustrated and push back.

The question is "What is a 95% confidence interval for a population mean?" Which would be the best explanation? If you have a better explanation, please share. Remember keep it simple but accurate and less vague:

"We are 95% confident that the population mean is between the lower and upper bounds."

"If repeated samples were taken and 95% confidence intervals were computed for each sample, 95% of the intervals would contain the population mean."

"The population mean lies between the 2 bounds since 95% of the time confidence intervals contain the true mean"

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework question, and the online book at http://onlinestatbook.com/lms/estimation/confidence.html contains the exact wording of one of the answers along with a few paragraphs your "friend" should fight any frustration to read.

Comment: Steve, this isn't a HW question and yes, I'm borrowing words but I want to use the best words that capture the meaning. In fact all of these explanations have been taken from sources because they are seen as "conventional" and "technical." I want something different and simpler if there is one.

Comment: I agree that the "correct" answer in the multiple choice question at the link I gave is the best one. Neither of your other answers is good. The first uses the notion of "95% confidence," which is not a clearly-defined notion, and the third one is simply wrong. You can't say "this is the case" about something that is the case 95% of the time.

Comment: I think the problem with the second one is that it is self-referencing. How can a beginner possibly know what you're talking about? Remember the purpose is to make the explanation less confusing

Comment: You asked for the best explanation of three. The second is the best. If you want something better than any of your choices, you could say that the confidence interval is an interval estimate of the true population mean. The best point estimate based on the sample data is the average of the sample data, but the sample is a sample, so the average of the sample data is unlikely to be exactly the population mean. Better to give an interval estimate, and the 95% confidence interval is constructed so that (under certain assumptions) it contains the population mean for 95% of all possible samples.